# React Native FlatList loop over 2 arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array with objects and within these objects there's a `places` key that also has an array with objects, here's the array:

```
cities = [
        {
            name: 'New York City',
            avatar: 'new-york-city.png',
            places: [
                {
                    name: 'Times Square',
                    avatar: 'times-square.png'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Manhattan',
                    avatar: 'manhattan.png'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Los Angeles',
            avatar: 'la.png',
            places: [
                {
                    name: 'Hollywood Boulevard',
                    avatar: 'hollywood-boulevard.png'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Venice Beach',
                    avatar: 'venice-beach.png'
                }
            ]
        },
    ];
```

With FlatList obviously it loops over the first array but in some cases I also need to access the objects that're inside the `places` key.

Knowing that FlatList only loops over the first array, how can I loop over the array that is inside of `places` key through FlatList and access it?

```
<FlatList
    data={cities}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <City data={item} />}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
/>
```

Comment: Do you want to have the places on the same level as the cities and display them the same?
If not, why not access them in your City component?

Comment: Yes, I am accessing them in my City component, but I can only access them using `data.places[0].name`, I want to access the with `data.places.name`. data is the prop passed to City which has the value `item`

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow. `places` is an Array, so you need to access its values with the index, or iterate over it.  
 What do you expect `data.places.name` to be?